# performance issues using PropertyUtilsBean.getProperty()

Tags: java, reflection, javabeans, apache-commons

I am currently having some performance issues using PropertyUtilsBean.getProperty to evaluate some property-expressions like:

```
obj.propert1.coolMap[1].property
```

I am currently using PropertyUtilsBean.getProperty for this, but it has to be executed a lot of times and I can see the enormous amount of wasted CPU time in JProfiler.
As the expression for each occurance never changes, I would like to sort of pre-initialize the property accessor. In an older version of my software I used reflection to save an instance of the getMethod so all I had to do, was to call the method for a given object. In the current version we added support for more complex expressions and therefore switched to PropertyUtilsBean ... seems this was a bad decision from a performance point of view.

Is there a way to have reusable access to a property which is able to interpret such property expressions as PropertyUtilsBean understands them? I would really like to be able to do this without implementing it manually.

Comment: Your scenario is still a bit unclear; is the property being read repeatedly on the same object, or are you looking at the same property on a number of different objects?

Comment: The object changes, but the expression doesn't. So I need to evaluate the same expression thousands of times. Using reflection I can save a reference to the function object and simply invoke that passing the current object as a parameter. This is a lot faster.